# i am getting "java.lang.Exception: Method tearDown should have no parameters" for below code & result.getStatus is null

Tags: java, selenium, junit

i am getting  "java.lang.Exception: Method tearDown should have no parameters" for below code & result.getStatus is null

i have JUnit to run cases

```
package com;


import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;


public class DeleteLeter {


    @Test
    public void testw() throws Exception{
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://e4allapac");
        int a =10;
        int b=20;
        Assert.assertEquals(a, b);

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(ITestResult result){
        System.out.println(result.getStatus());
        if(ITestResult.FAILURE==result.getStatus())
            System.out.println("Fail");
    }

}
```

Comment: Delete the `tearDown` method and it will be fine. jUnit will do its job out of box

Comment: i need to get the status of the test so if it fails then i add code to capture the screenshot

Comment: aah, I see that you're mixing jUnit and testNg. Decide on one for the beginning

Comment: if i use @Test (TestNG)  - Then it display main method missing & if i add@Test(JUnit) then i get "java.lang.Exception: Method tearDown should have no parameters"

Please suggest

Comment: One or the other; do one well.  I would suggest that you stop confusing yourself.

Comment: we use JUnit strictly & My requirement is @After i need to check the status of the testcase and if it fails then i need to add capturescreen shot code...
Now pls suggest how i can achieve this

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to implement a `TestWatcher` rule - http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/index.html.

The basic idea is that you create a class which extends the TestWatcher class, attach it as a `@Rule` to your test suite and then it will get notified when a test fails.

```
public class MyWatcher extends TestWatcher {
  @Override
  protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
      // do whatever Selenium magic here.
  }
}

public class MyTests { 
  @Rule
  public final MyWatcher myWatcher = new MyWatcher();

  @Test
  public void testMethod() {
      // test stuff goes in here
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome... Thank you all.